# How to implement BST functions insert() and split() based upon rank?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to figure out how to implement code to the functions of insert() (which inserts an element into the tree), split() (which splits the tree on rank r into two trees of L and R. L containing ranks < r and R containing ranks >= r. For this assignment, I am dumbfounded. I believe I have the code for my insert correct for it works:

```
Node *insert(Node *T, int v, int r)
{
    if(T == nullptr)
    {
        return new Node(v);
    }
    int rank = T->left ? T->left->size : 0;
    
    if (r <= rank)
    {
        T -> left = insert(T -> left, v, rank);
    }
    else
    {
        T -> left = insert(T -> left, v, r - rank - 1);
    }
    fix_size(T);
    return T;
}
```

For my split() function, I barely have anything that works. Can someone explain the algorithm of how to complete these two functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we're dealing with unbalanced BSTs here (balance makes this harder).

Splitting the null tree is trivial (return (null, null)).

Given a non-null tree T, compare the rank of the root to r. If it's less, then recursively split the right child to get (R<, R≥) and return (T′, R≥) where T′ is T with the right child of the root replaced by R<. Similarity, if the rank of the root is greater than or equal to r, then recursively split the left child into (L<, L≥) and return (L<, T′′) where T′′ is T with the left child of the root replaced by L≥.

This has a slick iterative implementation with `Node**` pointers that I will leave as an exercise.